# USING section ignored in EXECUTE...USING in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.3

I try to make a sequence dynamically through EXECUTE..USING and I have problems to pass the parameters into it. According to [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), I understand that the correct form should be this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_dyn_seq( /* some params */ ) 
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
  _seq_name text;
  _min integer;
  _max integer;
BEGIN
  /*
    some code assigning the variables
    sample values:
    _seq_name := 'hu01/1/0_seq';
    _min := 101;
    _max := 500;
  */    
  EXECUTE 'CREATE SEQUENCE "' || _seq_name || '" MINVALUE $1 MAXVALUE $2 ' 
  USING _min::INT, _max::INT;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I added quotation marks and the _seq_name itself seems fine. However, when I insert these values, it throws following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: CREATE SEQUENCE "hu01/1/0_seq" MINVALUE $1 MAXVALUE $2
```

I also tried an alternative syntax of the EXECUTE, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16214463/1801588):

```
EXECUTE 
  'CREATE SEQUENCE "' || _seq_name || '" MINVALUE ' || $1 || ' MAXVALUE ' || $2  
  USING _min::INT, _max::INT;
```

Now the error is different:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "hu01"
LINE 1: CREATE SEQUENCE "hu01/1/0_seq" MINVALUE hu01 MAXVALUE 1
```

Dollar signs now translate, but the variables in the USING section are overridden by parts of the `_seq_name` variable. I tried to replace slashes in the sequence name by underscores, but nothing changed.

I also tried it through `format()` combined with USING, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12995424/1801588), but nothing changed, the same errors occur:

```
EXECUTE format('CREATE SEQUENCE %I MINVALUE $1 MAXVALUE $2 ', _seq_name) 
USING _min::INT, _max::INT;

EXECUTE format('CREATE SEQUENCE %I MINVALUE ' || $1 || ' MAXVALUE ' || $2, _nazev_seq) 
USING _min::INT, _max::INT;
```

Then I completely replaced the USING part with `format()` arguments:

```
EXECUTE format('CREATE SEQUENCE %I MINVALUE %L MAXVALUE %L ', _seq_name, _min::INT, _max::INT);
```

Now I am almost where I want to be, the error is different:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'101'"
LINE 1: CREATE SEQUENCE "hu01/1/0_seq" MINVALUE '101' MAXVALUE '500'...
```

I found a question on "[how to use integer within FORMAT()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22656716/1801588)" and one of its answers suggests `%s`. Now it works:

```
EXECUTE format('CREATE SEQUENCE %I MINVALUE %s MAXVALUE %s ', _seq_name, _min, _max);
```

However, [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22675836/1801588) suggested having the integers in the USING section, which is what I would do if it wasn't bugged. My "solution" feels to be a dirty workaround and I would like to do it right, so my question is:

**Why the USING section and dollar-sign-escaped values don't work for me?**

Comment: This is intended. *Another restriction on parameter symbols is that they only work in SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE commands.* http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE SEQUENCE "' || _seq_name || '" MINVALUE $1 MAXVALUE $2 ' 
USING _min::INT, _max::INT;
```

This won't work, because parameter substitution will work [only within SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

> Another restriction on parameter symbols is that they only work in SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE commands. Only these statements has execution plan and only these statements should be parametrized.

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE SEQUENCE "' || _seq_name || '" MINVALUE ' || $1 || ' MAXVALUE ' || $2  
USING _min::INT, _max::INT;
```

This won't work, because in that context `$1` refers to the [1st argument](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTION-ARGUMENTS) of the function.

```
EXECUTE format('CREATE SEQUENCE %I MINVALUE %L MAXVALUE %L ', _seq_name, _min::INT, _max::INT);
```

This won't work, because both `MINVALUE` & `MAXVALUE` options of `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement only accepts integers, not texts (& no implicit cast will be done in ddl).

```
EXECUTE format('CREATE SEQUENCE %I MINVALUE %s MAXVALUE %s ', _seq_name, _min, _max);
```

This is perfectly safe as long as `_min` & `_max` is some type of integer. When they are not, use explicit cast here.